# UITableViewCell and UICollectionViewCell click, tap spring animation Extension

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell, uiviewanimation

Following is my code for spring animation

```
 var transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
     transform = transform.scaledBy(x: 0.96, y: 0.96)
     UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: [], animations: {
       self.transform = transform
     }, completion: nil)
```

Above code is working fine I want to create extension whenever my UITableViewCell and UICollectionViewCell is tapped or clicked I want this Spring animation effect.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to separately write two extensions to each **UITableViewCell** and **UICollectionViewCell**

UITableViewCell Extension

```
extension UITableViewCell {
    func showAnimation()  {
        var transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            transform = transform.scaledBy(x: 0.96, y: 0.96)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: [], animations: {
              self.transform = transform
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Now you can call the **showAnimation()** when user click

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.showAnimation()
 }
```

Do the same  thing for UIcollectionViewCell also